# Passenger 2.2.5 - Apache turn off friendly Error Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm in production mode with Passenger 2.2.5 and Apache and would like to get rid of the friendly error messages. Preferably I would just like to see a 404 if anything goes wrong.

I know Passenger 3.0 offers the PassengerFriendlyError off option, but afaik, 2.2.5 does not.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that in 2.2.5 is to modify the Phusion Passenger error templates. No other way.